# Angular validation on reactive form should toggle on or off if empty, but does not toggle if input is emptied

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I've built a simple form using Angular Reactive Forms. I have a custom Validator function, which checks the format of a phone number input. I want to allow an empty input if the users chooses not to enter a phone number, but then validate their entry if they enter one.

To achieve this, I subscribe to the value changes on the form control and use the `setValidators` method to toggle the validation if the field is empty or not:

```
phoneControl.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
  if (phoneControl.value === "") {
    phoneControl.setValidators(null);
  } else {
    phoneControl.setValidators(this.phoneValidator());
  }
});
```

Please see the [full code on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-phone-number-validation-changes).

The code works initially, `form.valid` is true. When I enter a number it turns on the validation and then successfully validates it according to my RegEx and shows an error.

However, when I empty the field, the error does not disappear and the form form is still invalid, even though my code should set the validator to `null`. You can see this in the StackBlitz example above.

I can't figure out why this is happening. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When dynamically setting validators, we need to call **[`updateValueAndValidity()`](http://%20%20%20%20const%20newControl%20=%20this.fb.control('');%20%20%20%20%20this.emails.push(newControl);)**. Also remember to add `emitEvent: false`, that means that the `valueChanges` will not be triggered (to prevent looping). So change your code to:

```ts
phoneControl.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
  if (phoneControl.value === "") {
    phoneControl.setValidators(null);
    // or
    // phoneControl.setValidators([]);
    // or as mentioned by Tilak
    // phoneControl.clearValidators();
  } else {
    phoneControl.setValidators(this.phoneValidator());
  }
  phoneControl.updateValueAndValidity({emitEvent: false});
});
```

Your **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-phone-number-validation-changes-wxcznt?file=src/app/form/form.component.ts)**

Comment: Oh! So that's why the formControl was emitting random events! `{emitEvent: false}` with `updateValueAndValidity`! This helped. Made my code stable

Answer (score 2):

I will recommend you to do this way -

```
if (phoneControl.value === "") {
        phoneControl.clearValidators();
} else {
        phoneControl.setValidators(this.phoneValidator());
}
phoneControl.updateValueAndValidity({emitEvent: false});
```

Clearing validator is a better way than setting it to null.

Answer (score 2):

For validating Phone Number Input, you can use **pattern** validator of **@rxweb/reactive-form-validators**.

You just have to mention the phone number regex in your formControl like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.userFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
            phoneNumber:['', RxwebValidators.pattern({expression:{'onlyPhoneNumber': /^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}$/} })], 
        });
    }
```

For error message, you can bind the message in you app.component.ts like this:

```
ngOnInit(){
    ReactiveFormConfig.set({"validationMessage":{"onlyPhoneNumber":"Invalid phone number"}});
  }
```

This is the complete HTML code:

```
<div>
  <form  [formGroup]="userFormGroup">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Phone Number</label>
      <input type="text" formControlName="phoneNumber" class="form-control"  />
     <small class="form-text text-danger" *ngIf="userFormGroup.controls.phoneNumber.errors">{{userFormGroup.controls.phoneNumber.errors.onlyPhoneNumber.message}}<br/></small>  
    </div>
    <button [disabled]="!userFormGroup.valid" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here is the complete Component code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from "@angular/forms"
import { RxwebValidators } from '@rxweb/reactive-form-validators';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-pattern-add-validator',
    templateUrl: './pattern-add.component.html'
})
export class PatternAddValidatorComponent implements OnInit {
    userFormGroup: FormGroup

    constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder )
    { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.userFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
            phoneNumber:['', RxwebValidators.pattern({expression:{'onlyPhoneNumber': /^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}$/} })], 
        });
    }
}
```

**Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q2hwzq?file=src/app/pattern-add.component.ts)**

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same "issue" many times. And it is somehow intended. It will do the same with "classic" validators (non-custom).

What I've been doing is something similar to this :

```js
phoneControl.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
  if (phoneControl.value === "") {
    phoneControl.reset();
    phoneControl.markAsPristine();
    phoneControl.markAsUntouched();
    phoneControl.updateValueAndValidity();
  } else {
    phoneControl.setValidators(this.phoneValidator());
  }
});
```

If you use only `updateValueAndValidity()` your form will say it is in valid state even when the value is empty.

Answer (score 0):

It should just be fine by editing the validator itself:

```
  isValidPhoneNumber(phoneNumber: string) {
    if(phoneNumber === "")return true;
    return new RegExp(/^[ 0 ]{1,1}?[0-9- ]{9,15}$/).test(phoneNumber);
  }
```

and removing the subscription.

Comment: How does this solve it? Does the new RegExp allow it to be empty, as well as check the value if the user has entered some characters?

Comment: If the value is empty, then skip the Regexp validation and just return true, if not do the normal validation.